# css position of button in menu

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a menu with menu which looks like this :

```
<div class="menuContainer">
<div id="titlebarDiv" style="float: left;">
<a>Item 1</a>
<div id="container">
     <input type="button" value="0" class="masterPageNotifier" style="height: 30px;"onclick="NotifierButtonClicked()" />
     <input type="hidden" value="" class="mehidden" />
    <ul class="selectBox" />
    </div>
<a>Item 2</a>
<a>Item 3</a>
<a>Item 4</a>
<a>Item 5</a>
<div>
<div>
```

as you can see in between i have a `div` with a button inside, on click of the button, ul with `class="selectbox"` will slide down and show the items. Problem here is that i can get menu to work on itself, but as soon as i add button in between, button is moving everything down 1 row, and when i click on the button `.menuContainers` background gets stretched. i want to make it like facebook when notification button is clicked.i tryed with absolute position on container div, but without luck.

**CSS**:

```
   input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background:#5CCD00;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#5CCD00 0%,#4AA400 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#5CCD00),color-stop(100%,#4AA400));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5CCD00 0%,#4AA400 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#5CCD00 0%,#4AA400 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#5CCD00 0%,#4AA400 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#5CCD00 0%,#4AA400 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5CCD00',endColorstr='#4AA400',GradientType=0);
    padding:10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #459A00;
    }

.menuContainer
{
width: 1000px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
overflow: hidden; 
background-color: purple;
}


function NotifierButtonClicked() {
    if (checked == false) {
        checked = true;

        GetNotificationsForUser();

        $('.selectBox').slideToggle(200).css('borderTop', 'none');
        $('.selectBox li').click(function () {
            $('.selectBox').slideUp(200);
        });

        //$('.masterPageNotifier').val("0");
    }
    else if (checked == true) {
        checked = false;
        $('.selectBox').slideUp(200);
    }

}
```

Thats how it looks: [image]

Comment: try this with ur button style="Margin:0;"

Comment: doesnt helped, ive updated my question with a picture

Comment: Could you post the js for NotifierButtonClicked()

Comment: That is because you have a block-level `<div>` element among inline `<a>` elements. The block element will force subsequent inline elements to the next line. You should consider reformatting your menu, too. I would recommend nesting each item in a `<li>` item itself. That makes a lot more semantic sense.

Comment: can i have div tag inside of ul? I just reformated it but its still gives same problems

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "container" `<div>` to stay on the same line as your `<a>` elements by adding this:

```
#container {  display:inline-block; width:50px; }
```

I tested in Chrome.  Of course, I can't tell if your JavaScript is still working after this change, because what you posted is not complete ("checked" is not defined).